# Command Bus Pattern for Complex Commands

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel and going along with my first project in it. Till now I have loved every bit of what Laravel offers.

From Laracast I came to know about Command Bus pattern which jeffrey followed in his LaraBook Series so I decided to use the same. Till now it was good but now I am under situation I need to sort out.
https://github.com/laracasts/Commander

Basically I need to create a subscriber (form is there for the same) which actually contains lot of actions.

1. creating company
2. creating admin user
3. assigning few other things ( like states, roles) to admin user..

I don't think these are the things I should manage through events.. These all makes up the process of adding a subscriber. s

I am stucked at first step itself, Do I define these much parameters in constructor of my CommandObject?

Further in my CommandHalnder should I do all those sub tasks? What will be the preferred way to approach this following the command bus pattern?

Comment: what of the two solutions did you preferred to use? the [listener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26423762/662581) or the [individual commands for each of the actions you listed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26345107/662581)

Comment: I ended up passing array to command object and then I handled company creation and user creation in command handler and further option tasks through event handler.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't have to be scared to use multiple events. For example: create an event listener that listens for the event that fires when a "company" is created. That event listener should fire the CreateCompanyAdmin command. You only need to make sure to have the right decorated Command bus is injected at the place where the event is handled.

Also create a listener that listens for the event that fires when the admin is created. That event listener in turn should create and fire a command that sets up the admin roles for that admin. Don't be scared to reuse the command pattern from the event listeners on.

Like so, you could reuse the CreateCompanyAdmin command when an existing admin adds an extra, new admin to an existing company.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think those are three separate actions that should be handled in three separate places. In other words, create three listeners for the same event, each one of them handling one of the steps you listed.

As for passing that many parameters to your CommandObject constructor, such a thing is usually a sign that you need to break up your logic into smaller chunks.

Why don't you create three individual commands for each of the actions you listed, instead of a single command object that does everything? You should keep your classes as simple as possible (single responsibility principle and all that) and I would say this should also apply to command objects.

I understand what you say about them being all part of the same action - the process of adding a subscriber - but what about in the future if/when this process changes and you need additional steps, or need to remove existing steps? You'll have to change your whole logic instead of simply adding or removing a couple of lines (creating the command object and executing it).

Comment: Thanks for aswering.. I gave lot of thoughts about three  different commands but somehow it am not buying this idea.. All am really doing is adding a subscriber and that's what the command should be. Create company, create admin user these command just wouldn't make any sense.. Instead I think of it like there are 3 subprocess that makes up adding subscriber process.

Comment: I am not sure about event as well.. Event should be fired when subscriber has been added, so if I need to do something after that I would go with event..

Comment: Well, to be honest, I haven't really bought into this command-driver architecture thing, at least not yet. I may yet see the light when using it in a project where it really shines but so far it just seems like a really contrived way of using events.

As for having three commands, that's obviously something you need to decide for yourself. I certainly wouldn't do a single command object that does so much but I also understand your concerns about breaking apart what seems to be a single action, but it's not. Still, there's really no right or wrong here. Just do what feels best for you.

Comment: I hear you. Thanks for explaining the possible options. and you are right on that it comes to preference.